# Passing type-casted variables to a method for generic compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a system which takes a class name and is enumerated by [soot](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Tutorials) -- which gives us details such as all the methods in the class, modifiers of said class, visibility, arguments for methods, and much more.

What I do is take that information and build a java file where I instantiate that class (through reflection or regular instantiation), call each method member of that class, then compile it and use that elsewhere in our system.  I've got it working for 98~ of my test cases.  The 2% that it fails on are when the object that is an argument of a method is an inner class (package.path.here.ClassName$InnerClass as an variable type).

Please note: **I do not care what is in the method**, I only care about the signature in the Enumeration phase.

The compiler error I get is `cannot find symbol` when I try to compile a class that has a method member who's arguments include `package.path.here.ClassName$InnerClass`.

So I my input is simple `package.path.here.ToEnumerate`:

```
package package.path.here;

public class ToEnumerate {
     public ToEnumerate() {
        //irrelevant code here
     }

     public void method1(some.other.package.OtherClass$InnerClass c, long a) {
        // irrelevant code here
     }

     public void method1(int x, long b) {
        // irrelevant code here
     }

     public void method1(yet.another.package.YetAnotherClass b, long a) {
         // irrelevant code here
     }

     public void method2(long b, boolean a) {
        // irrelevant code here
     }

     public int method3(int x) {
         // irrelevant code here
     }

}
```

Through my system I would generate a Java file which looks like this:

```
package package.path.here;
// all necessary imports are auto generated
public class ToEnumerate_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToEnumerate inst = new ToEnumerate();
        Object obj = new Object();
        inst.method1((some.other.package.OtherClass$InnerClass) obj, (long) -1);
        inst.method1((int)-1, (long)-1);
        inst.method1((yet.another.package.YetAnotherClass) obj, (long) -1);
        inst.method2((long)-1, false);
        inst.method3((int)-1);
    }
}
```

When I compile that with: `javac -cp /path/to/all/my/classes ToEnumerate_Main.java` I get the `cannot find symbol` in reference to an inner class.  The carrot points to period between the last package path and the class name:

```
ToEnumerate_Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
inst.method1((some.other.package.OtherClass$InnerClass) obj, (long) -1);
                                ^
symbol:   class OtherClass$InnerClass
location: package some.other.package
```

Even though I can find the file at that path, which is also included in my `-cp` argument to `javac`.

If I change the ToEnumerate_Main to send certain object-based variables `nulls` I get an `reference to method1 is ambiguous` as you would expect from the signatures if one tried to send a `null`.

I'm not quite sure why the `cannot find symbol` error is thrown at compilation because I the file most certainly exists. Any help in identifying either why this error is thrown, why the `javac -cp...` doesn't find the file, or a way to get this work would be very appreciated.

Comment: what if you replace `'$'` with `'.'` - `some.other.package.OtherClass.InnerClass`

Comment: Please post that as an answer so I can give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: it works? cool then. no need for credits:)